# iOS - Does publishing on Facebook wall require review?

Tags: ios, facebook, publish

In my iOS app, I want to allow user to share pictures by posting to their wall, hence it will ask the user to grant `publish_actions` permission to the app when they click the share button. While I can publish it to the wall with developer's Facebook account without any problem, I can't do that with another Facebook account, which does not have any role in the Facebook app, the following error will occur:

```
2014-08-27 16:12:30.896 myApp[8139:907] permission granted, starting to publish...
2014-08-27 16:12:31.154 myApp[8139:907] Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x1f056860 {com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=403, com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 200;
            message = "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 403;
}, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=<FBSession: 0x1ddfb720, state: FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended, loginHandler: 0x1ddf14d0, appID: (__myApp's Facebook appID__), urlSchemeSuffix: , tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: 0x1ddc1dc0>, expirationDate: 2014-10-26 08:12:28 +0000, refreshDate: 2014-08-27 08:12:30 +0000, attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(
    status,
    permission
)>}
```

After I clicked the share button with the non-developer account, it never prompt to ask for the `publish_actions` permission, which it does when I am using developer's account. Meanwhile, when I am using developer's account, the app asks for the permission with a red dialogue as in this screen capture:

[image]

And I've read some other post related to this issue, some said that Facebook implemented new policy, which requires all apps that will publish materials to submit a review before any user other than the developer can publish anything. Is this true? If yes, where can I find that policy update? I tried to look for that in Facebook's developer page, but I only found statements regarding the need to review if Facebook login ask for permission other than the basic info like public_profile, etc ([Login review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review)). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as said [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/overview/v2.1#review),

> Apps may ask for the following permissions from any person **without** submitting for review by
> Facebook:
>
> public_profile
>
> email
>
> user_friends

It is valid for all new apps. Old apps still can use old API.

Read more about FB review: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review